# How to add information into a purchase table

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem adding a purchase information to the table. I have created a shopping cart and when checking out there is a purchase button. Before i go ahead, this is the way my tables are structured:

Purchase (TABLE):

- PurchaseID (Primary Key)
- FrameNumber (Foreign Key)
- Date
- Email

BikeStock:

- FrameNumber (Primary Key)
- Purchase ID (Foreign Key) - Links to purchase table.
- BikeCode (Foreign Key) - links to the bike table.

When someone clicks the purchase table, i want a purchase ID to be entered, FrameNumber to be grabbed from the Bikestock table where Bikecode = 'the code of the bike i wish to purchase'.

what i have so far is this:

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("connection.php");

$sql = "SELECT b.FrameNumber, b.BikeCode, p.FrameNumber FROM BikeStock b LEFT JOIN Purchase p on b.FrameNumber = p.FrameNumber WHERE b.bikecode = 'MABE2012-5'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die('Query1 failed: ' . mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$framenumber = $row[0];

echo $framenumber . "<br>";

}
$PurchaseID = (rand(1,24));
$date = date("d/m/Y");
$Email = $_SESSION["user"];

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO Purchase VALUES (\"$date\",\"$PurchaseID\",\"$Email\", \"$framenumber\")";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1) or die('Query2 failed: ' . mysqli_error($con));

    echo $date . "<br>";
    echo $PurchaseID . "<br>";
    echo $Email . "<br>";

?>
```

Im not to sure how i would add the $bikecode information, also I keep getting duplicated entries with the primary key as it chooses random numbers and the framenumber keeps getting copied but its a foreign key so if one framenumber is used it must choose another one and if it runs out of frame numbers i want it to say out of stock.

Help would be really appreciated, if i am unclear please tell me where and i will sort it out.

Comment: no its just choosing the first row and the first row is 0

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

1) change your Purchase table to include an auto increment primary key. Don't use a random number.
2) change this insert:

> INSERT INTO Purchase VALUES

to something more like:

> INSERT INTO Purchase ( PurchaseID, FrameNumber, ...) VALUES ?, ?, ...

and use a prepared statement.

3) MySQL is happier with dates if you format them like YYYY-MM-DD.
4) Check for the 'frame out of stock' before you let it be added to the shopping cart.

Comment: Hi ethrbunny, Thank you for your advice. I will be adding the auto-increment and the date would be in this format date("Y/m/d"); i did the out of stock in the products page but there's a limited amount of frame numbers when the frame numbers are all used i want it to say out of stock.

Comment: frame numbers or frame inventory?

Comment: frame inventory. So for bikecode "123" there are 3 bikes in stock with the frame numbers "w31", "w32", "w33"

Comment: Seriously - deal with limited inventory before you get to the order entry phase. Relying on a foreign key to block the insert (and trapping the error) is a bit precarious.

Comment: Im doing it for a school project. They supplied me with the sample data and the limited inventory. I don't have to add a payment system just the information from basket added and the out of stock frame number is not priority aswell.

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to trap the failed insert and figure out which error you got. Not ideal but it sounds like you are stuck with this.

Comment: ahh, but im not to sure how i would choose only one frame number from three framenumbers that are equal to my bikecode. Any ideas?

Comment: I was able to solve this problem. However, the only error i am having is framenumbers are being repeated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20847/discussion-between-ethrbunny-and-moe)